# probability of forming a loop

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have $n$ nodes. Now enumerate all the pairs and connect them with a string by probability $p$. What's the probability of forming at least one loop?

I am not sure if there is a closed formula to represent the probability for any $n$.

Comment: Are you asking for the existence of some loop (with arbitrary length) within the $n$ vertices or the probability that there is precisely one loop connecting all nodes?

Comment: @AndreasLenz existence of any loop. Since, the primary question is about the simulation, that's why I am not sure if there is a closed formula.

Comment: probability in how many steps? For example, if you allow $n+1$ steps, you'll always have a loop.

Comment: @SayanDutta pls see my update

Comment: The keywords you are looking for: *Erdos-Renyi random graph*

Comment: @Sal it is only for the expectation of K-loop, seems still far away from the probability of  existence of loop.